# Not applying css in struts application while using pretty url

Tags: java, struts, web.xml

I am doing web application in struts using jsp.I used pretty url's.[i.e.elimination of .do,? ]
When i enter simple url like ->http://localhost:8084/project Name/page.jsp it will show that page with css applied.
But when i enter another page like->http://localhost:8084/project Name/page/8 it will not show the page with the css applied.
Why css is not applying what changes should be made in web.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Not a good practice to use the URL's directly in struts , that does not truly go with mvc2 pattern , always use forward action for this type of work.

Using a central relative css is the best practice .